# Formatting text in VIM while preserving newlines

Tags: vim

[image]

I have a bunch of markdown files that I want to reformat to maximize the textwidth. My `fo` are set to:

```
formatoptions=2tcqn
```

those options stand for:

```
t   Auto-wrap text using textwidth
c   Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
    leader automatically.
q   Allow formatting of comments with "gq".
n   When formatting text, recognize numbered lists
```

`textwidth` is also set to a reasonable value.

The problem I have is when I try to format multiple paragraphs containing linebreaks with trailing spaces (which is the markdown way to break a line). Those linebreaks are removed when formating using `gq`.
Is there a way to tell VIM to leave those linebreaks (including the trailing whitespaces) alone?

P.S. in the animated gif I first select the whole paragraph using `vap` and then use `gq` to format it. Since this does not yield the desired behavior, I revert the changes and perform the formatting linewise.

Comment: I just had a look at `:help fo-table`: Would the `w` option not do what you are looking for?

Comment: @Xophmeister that's something I already tried but it does not do what I need unfortunately

Comment: I'm confused... "is there a way to tell VIM not leave those linebreaks alone?". Do you mean, "is there a way to tell VIM to leave those linebreaks alone?"

Comment: @Conner typo...fixed that

Answer (score 1):

The only real option to obtain the desired behavior is to set a `formatprg` that formats markdown documents in the way you'd like. The internal vim formatter is complicated and not customizable using vim settings other than using `formatprg` to set a different program (for example, `par` is often used but would not help in this case).

Comment: I didn't know about `par`, quite nice and described in more detail [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/). But you are right it does not help in this case.